# Intellisense for F# in visual studio 2012 not working

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

To be precise it pops up the autocomplete box when I press `<ctrl-space>`. However after approximately 500ms the popup disappears. This happens all the time without fail. When I switch to a C# for VB.Net project the intellisense popup has no problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Resharper is not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a fix in case anybody else has this problem.

In your F# solution add a single C# class library. It doesn't matter what it is called. I call mine IntellisenseFix. Ignore the project and continue editing your F# project but now intellisense works correctly.

If you delete your C# class library from the project then intellisense stops working.

It doesn't have to make sense it just has to work :)

Comment: Already voted up. I wish I could give a second vote for this: "It doesn't have to make sense it just has to work :)"